# is there an easier way to set a view's origin and size on iphone

Tags: iphone, frame, cgpoint

Shorter than

```
CGRect rect = self.webView.frame;
rect.origin = CGPointMake(0, 120);
self.webView.frame = rect;
```

Or is this the shortest way (or efficient)

Answer (score 3):

You can use CGRectMake. Four parameters.. x, y, width, height, all floats. Like this: `self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);`

Comment: what about only for origin for example?

Comment: What you posted is probably the best way for adjusting just the origin. At least, as far as I know..

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to position a view.  As donkim suggested, you could use CGRectMake.  Other options include setting the transform, or setting the center, if those are easier to deal with.  Usually, CGRectMake is the way to go, but I'd like to put these methods here just in case they are more useful in your case:

```
//Sets the webView's center, automatically adjusting the frame
self.webView.center = CGPointMake(x,y);
```

or

```
//Moves where the webview shows up away from its current location, but does not technically adjust its location.
self.webView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,120);
```

Comment: Something like this ought to work: self.webView.frame = (CGRect){0,120,self.webView.frame.size};  Or if not, self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(0,120,self.webView.frame.size.width, self.webView.frame.size.height);